# Get XFT template by form name

Tags: adobe, abap, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

Please let me know if there is a method by which we can get the XFT template of the Adobe Form in SAP. Basically I want to input form name ('Z_INVOICE', for example) and get back XFT template of the form in xstring format.

Comment: Maybe get some inspiration from the demo program `RSXFT_XFT_API_DEMO`...

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply, but I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve XFT layout of already existing form rather than write XFT template from scratch.

Comment: I investigated more in depth. It seems that SAP proposes to generate XFT files, that you may inject them to the Adobe Server to produce forms (see code inside CL_FP_PDF_OBJECT), but I don't see any evidence in SAP code of extracting XFT from Adobe Forms out of the Adobe Server. Sorry, I can't help more.

Comment: thank you for your assistance, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sandra probably missed `_DOWNLOAD` method of `CL_FP_PDF_OBJECT` class does exactly what you want, it downloads all the files that are created during PDF generation.

Moreover, it is explicitly confirmed [in ADS help](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_scm41/helpdata/en/04/8e0a414f3af223e10000000a155106/frameset.htm) and list of files is given:

[image]

Provided you need this occasionally, the only thing you should do is to put a breakpoint in method `_DOWNLOAD` and initiate document output by standard means catching the necessary file, not to forget setting `lv_download` to `true` in debugger. File will be downloaded to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\SAP\SAP GUI\tmp\` by default.

If you want this to be done automatically and/or on a regular basis, things get more complicated, you should inspect the call stack starting from print program (`SD_SDOC_PRINT01` on the screen) and find the most simplistic point which to emulate in code:

[image]

At first sight for me it seems that `FPCOMP_CREATE_PDX` is the most probable candidate, but it should be checked thoroughly.

After you choose the point to start, you inspect the parameters with which `FPCOMP_CREATE_PDX` is called while standard output and make a custom program that generates these parameters for arbitrary PDF form. The only thing you should set in your custom program, is that `lv_download` to be `true`, it can be dome thru enhancement in this method.

And voila, you'll get universal approach that can export XFT into directory for any PDF template.

Comment: for some unknown reason, I get PDFDOC, XFD and PDLOUT files, but not XFT

Comment: it help they say that `some of the files may not occur depending on the performed process`. I tried on my system and I also was not able to catch the XFT. Sorry, I cannot help more here, it needs more investigation